# Creating train/test CSV files for 10 fold cross validation experiment

Tags: python, r, csv, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a CSV file (main.csv) that has a unique column ID that also pertains to my image names (minus their .jpg extension).

I want to do 10 fold cross-validation and create a train and test CSV's such that the test CSV for each fold would only contain 10 percent of the original CSV.

Is there a straightforward path (already done) to do this?

Basically, I want my eventual train and test CSV files to have the same exact column names but designed such that I could perform 10 fold cross validation with them (aka randomly sampled/shuffled and 10% selected).

I don't mind using pandas in Python or R.

I am not planning to use Scikit-learn for cross-validation as I am using my own manual code that is why I need the chopped train and test CSV for each of the folds.

Comment: Take a look at [`sklearn.model_selection.KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could be looking for this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#X contains the dependent columns from the CSV file, and Y is the predicted variable
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

`test_size=0.33` This parameter says how much percentage of test data you want to split. All others would be train data.

```
X_train.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

This code will save the X_train data to a CSV file which is 33%

```
y_train.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

This code will save y_train data to CSV file which is 77%

This way, you can change the `random_state` value in the code each time and save  file, so that you would get a good suffle. The number does not signify anything. It randomly shuffles and splits the dataset. (Perhaps, if we know the logic behind each number, it wont be a random split anymore !! :))

After this you can apply manual K fold.

Comment: hey I just want to get the csv files for train and test as I am doing a manual method for k-fold and don't want to use the sklearn. Can you complete your answer to show how I can get the train test csv? Please check the last paragraph that I just added in my question. thanks

Comment: also why did you select random_state to be 42?

Comment: I think there should be an automatic way to create 10 fold cross-validation csv file